# How to git clone private repos within Vagrant VM, using host's SSH keys?

Tags: ssh, git, vagrant, puppet

I'm able to use PuppetLabs `vcsrepo` to clone public git repos, but I'd like to also be able to clone private repos, using the host's SSH keys.

What would the configuration look like for `Vagrantfile` and/or `manifests/default.pp` in order to accomplish this?

Answer (score 11):

I can't help with the Puppet part, but you can forward the SSH Agent by setting:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  # ...
end
```

This way the SSH connections (also make by git) try to use your private keys from the host.

Comment: There is an error that causes this to not work on Windows in most cases.

Comment: @ChaseSandmann can you give more info about the error? Do you have a link to the github issue? I have found this one but I think it's not the one because it seems related to VirtualBox 5: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6225

Answer (score 5):

Works on my machine!

Vagrantfile:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = '2'

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = 'precise64'
  config.vm.box_url = 'http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box'

  #
  # Use host authenticaton for git and maven.
  #
  # Ensure host private key is registered with host SSH agent:
  #
  # ssh-add -L
  # ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  # ssh-add -L
  #

  config.ssh.private_key_path = ['~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key', '~/.ssh/id_rsa']
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true

  config.vm.synced_folder "~/.m2", "/home/vagrant/.m2"

  config.vm.provision :shell, path: 'upgrade-puppet.sh'

  # Install puppet modules
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: 'bootstrap.rb', args: %w(
    puppetlabs-stdlib
    puppetlabs/apt
    puppetlabs/vcsrepo
  )

  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.options = ENV['PUPPET_OPTIONS']
  end
end
```

upgrade-puppet.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

apt-get install --yes lsb-release > /dev/null
DISTRIB_CODENAME=$(lsb_release --codename --short)
DEB="puppetlabs-release-${DISTRIB_CODENAME}.deb"
DEB_PROVIDES="/etc/apt/sources.list.d/puppetlabs.list" # Assume that this file's existence means we have the Puppet Labs repo added

if [ ! -e $DEB_PROVIDES ]
then
    # Print statement useful for debugging, but automated runs of this will interpret any output as an error
    # print "Could not find $DEB_PROVIDES - fetching and installing $DEB"
    wget -q http://apt.puppetlabs.com/$DEB
    sudo dpkg -i $DEB
fi
sudo apt-get update > /dev/null
sudo apt-get install --yes puppet > /dev/null

mkdir -p /etc/puppet
touch /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml
```

bootstrap.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

modules_dir = '/etc/puppet/modules'

puts `mkdir -p #{modules_dir}` unless File::exists? modules_dir

mods = ARGV

installed = `puppet module list`.split "\n"

mods.each do |mod|
  puts `puppet module install #{mod}` unless installed.any? { |i| i.include?(mod.sub('/','-')) }
end
```

manifests/default.pp:

```
exec { 'ssh know github':
  command => 'ssh -Tv git@github.com -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no; echo Success',
  path    => '/bin:/usr/bin',
  user    => 'vagrant'
}

vcsrepo { '/home/vagrant/a-private-repo':
  ensure   => latest,
  provider => git,
  source   => 'git@github.com:mcandre/a-private-repo.git',
  user     => 'vagrant',
  owner    => 'vagrant',
  group    => 'vagrant',
  require  => Exec['ssh know github']
}
```

Comment: `bootstrap.sh` needs to be `bootstrap.rb` for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

I know you are using Puppet but I got it up and running using this bash script (`provisioners/shell/application.setup.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

local_user=vagrant

if [ ! -n "$(grep "^bitbucket.org " /home/$local_user/.ssh/known_hosts)" ]; then 
    ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts 2>/dev/null;
fi

if [[ ! -d "/home/$local_user/app" ]]; then
    git clone git@bitbucket.org:czerasz/some-app.git /home/$local_user/app

    chown -R $local_user:$local_user /home/$local_user/app

    su - $local_user -c "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh && mkvirtualenv some-env && workon some-env && pip install -r /home/$local_user/app/requirements.txt"
fi
```

One could easily convert it to a puppet manifest...

Together with this `Vagrantfile`

```
config.vm.define "web1", primary: true do |web1_config|
    web1_config.ssh.forward_agent = true

    # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
    web1_config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.11.10"
    web1_config.vm.hostname = "web1.#{domain}"

    web1_config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provisioners/shell/python.setup.sh"
    web1_config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provisioners/shell/application.setup.sh"
end
```

The key point for me was that when I executed:

```
su - $local_user -c "ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts 2>/dev/null;"
su - $local_user -c "git clone git@bitbucket.org:czerasz/some-app.git /home/$local_user/app"
```

It didn't work out. As if the keys were not passed using `su`. So I cloned the repo as root and then changed ownership afterwards.

[This post](https://serverfault.com/a/667997/54393) was very helpful.

Comment: Mate..... I found a bunch of fairly unhelpful posts around this until yours. Cheers!!!